# How do i include ajax in PHP coding to display data in the same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to display data retrieved from the table in the same page. I know if i use ajax, work becomes easier. But how do i do it? I don't know anything about ajax. My current program is combined with html and php. The program is below. All i want is, when i click the button, the requested action and the data must be displayed in the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'DB';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_error()) 
{
die("couldn't connect" . $conn->connect_error());
}
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$blood = $_POST['BloodGroup'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
        $insert = "Insert into ins(Id, name, BloodGroup) values ('$id','$name', '$blood')" ;
        if($conn->query($insert) === TRUE) {
        echo ("Input data entered successfully");
        } else {
        echo ("Input data failed to be entered" . $conn->error());
        }
        $conn->close();
} elseif(isset($_POST['update'])) {

        $update = "update ins set Name='".$name."', BloodGroup='".$blood."' where Id='".$id."'";
        mysql_query($update);
        if($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
        echo ("Data updated successfully");
        } else {
        echo ("Data cant be updated" . $conn->error());
        }
        $conn->close();
} elseif(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $id = $_POST['Id'];
        $delete = "delete from ins where Id='".$id."'";
        if($conn->query($delete) === TRUE) {
        echo ("Data deleted successfully");
        } else {
        echo ("Data cant be updated" . $conn->error());
        }
        $conn->close();
}
else {
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM ins WHERE Id = ".$id;
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$retrieve))
{
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo '<table>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Blood Group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>'.$row[0].'</td>
<td>'.$row[1].'</td>
<td>'.$row[2].'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
//$row[0],$row[1],$row[2]';
}
 mysqli_free_result($result);
}}}
$conn->close();
?>

<h2>SELECT THE OPERATION YOU WANT TO PERFORM<h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Id: <input type="text" name="Id" />
Name: <Input type="text" name="Name" />
BloodGroup: <input type="text" name="BloodGroup" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert" />
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
<input type="submit" name="retrieve" value="retrieve" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your javascript for ajax?

Comment: @pjp I haven't started anything yet. Until yesterday i was trying using the same above program. If you could tell me clearly what i should do, i'll give it a try.

Comment: Then start. Start learning about how to ajax with javascript. Do you use jQuery in your project? Google AJAX with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "{php file url}",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } // data list need to sent 
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
     $("#div1").html(result); //#div1 is container element where you want to show output of ajax
  });
```

For more details refer 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

Just start learning jquery and jquery ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

you will find something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '', //write your php file url from where you want to get data
    data:{}, //to post data like data:{customerName:'xyz'},
    success: function(res){ //data returned from your php file
        console.log(res); //use data as per your need
    }
});
```